# Is there a ubuntu multudimenesional desktop tool?

Tags: unity

I want to be able to like rotate to new desktops on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is called "Desktop Cube". To enable it install `compiz configuration manager` (CCM)  and `compiz-plugins` from the software center or with `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` and `sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins`.

open the program, a warning will pop up becouse it is a powerfull tool but it is also quite easy to brake the system. Now under Desktop check the boxes of Desktop Cube and Rotate Cube.[image: selections]

if you click the buttons you can go into the appearance (Desktop Cube) and behavior and key bindings (Rotate Cube).